# Change default sort order in Nautilus "by type"

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, nautilus

The default sort order in `Files 3.30.5` (or `Nautilus`) has been changed to sorting alphabetically by name:

[image]

I prefer my view(s) to be sorted by type, so every time I open up a new instance, I don't have to configure the settings again and again:

[image]

I've searched for a while but I can't find a solution. I already have this key in `Nautilus`'s (internal) settings: `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/default-sort-order type`

[image]

Any other way to accomplish this?

> I've restarted it several times with: `killall nautilus`

Comment: I can confirm this... it's most likely the [same bug reported here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/636)...

Comment: Ah! Didn't know about it...I guess I'll have to wait ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. open nautilus
2. sort as you want
3. click right on the columns title and choose "Use Default"

Comment: Please format properly your answer, use syntax too

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for me; I know the answer was posted when I was using a different version and I'm currently using `3.36.2-5ee1fc0be`, but it just doesn't remember the settings for each folder. If I keep browsing, some folders go back to **sorted by name**. I did try also resetting Nautilus with `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.nautilus`.